# Extended subform field use own layout from template/html folder

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, form-fields-types

I've created an extended subform field type called `families.php`, basically I want to have my own custom layout for this custom field, it makes sense I don't want to mess up everything just for this case.

```
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/form/fields/subform.php';

class JFormFieldFamilies extends JFormFieldSubForm {

    /**
     * Field specs
     */
    protected $type = 'Families';
    protected $formsource;
    protected $layout = 'joomla.form.field.families'; // THIS IS IMPORTANT PART, see below
    protected $groupByFieldset = false;

    /**
     * Cached large array of the families.
     */
    public static $families = array();

    /**
     * Method to attach a JForm object to the field.
     */
    public function setup(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null)
    {
        if (!parent::setup($element, $value, $group))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Get the field families/options, a cache of ::getFamilies();
        if ( empty(static::$families) ) {
            $cache = JFactory::getCache();
            static::$families = $cache->call( array( 'JFormFieldFamilies', 'getFamilies' ) );
        }

        foreach (array('formsource', 'layout', 'groupByFieldset') as $attributeName)
        {
            $this->__set($attributeName, $element[$attributeName]);
        }

        if ($this->value && is_string($this->value))
        {
            // Guess here is the JSON string from 'default' attribute
            $this->value = json_decode($this->value, true);
        }

        if ( !$this->formsource && is_array($this->value) )
        {
            // Set the formsource the content of the static::$families
            $this->formsource = '
<form>
  <field name="family" type="list" label="Family" default="" value="Johnsons">
    '. // a list of static::$families .'
  </field>
  <field name="girls" type="list" multiple="true" label="Girls" default="400">
    '. // a list of static::$families[$family][$girls] .'
  </field>
  <field name="boys" type="list" multiple="true" label="Boys" default="Robert">
    '. // a list of static::$families[$family][$boys] .'
  </field>
</form>';
    }

    // these function are unchanged, perhaps I can remove from this file
    protected function __get() {}
    protected function getInput() {}
    protected function getName($fieldName) {}
    // this one is probably most important for me, changed
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case 'formsource':
                $this->formsource = (string) $value;
                break;

            case 'groupByFieldset':
                if ($value !== null)
                {
                    $value = (string) $value;
                    $this->groupByFieldset = !($value === 'false' || $value === 'off' || $value === '0');
                }
                break;

            case 'layout':
                $this->layout = (string) $value;

                // Make sure the layout is not empty.
                if (!$this->layout)
                {
                    // HERE'S THE TRICKY PART
                    // $this->layout = 'templates.MYTEMPLATE.html.layouts.joomla.form.field.families';
                    $this->layout = 'joomla.form.field.families';
                }

                break;

            default:
                parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }

    // a full array of families
    static function getFamilies() {}
}
```

In my `templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/form/field` folder I have `families.php`, basically a copy of the `subform/repeatable-table.php`. So far, if I use `joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table` it's working fine, however, my layout file isn't working and I don't know how to handle this, it's beyond me.

Basically I see an empty `<div class="controls">` inside my form.

Thanks for any inputs/suggestions.

Comment: Please improve the description of _how_ your layout "isn't working".

Comment: Oh God, I found [this](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout), I think I made it work. I will provide an answer as soon as I finish.

Comment: Great, just be sure to give us great content here.  Super clear questions/issues and correct/educational answers make this site a beautiful place for researchers.  We love code snippets, screenshots, links to documentation.  Give us the how and the why to the best of your ability. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom paths with `getLayoutPaths()` in the field:

```
protected function getLayoutPaths()
{
    return array_merge(
        array(JPATH_ROOT . '/templates/your_template/html/layouts'),
        parent::getLayoutPaths()
    );
}
```

If you have a field like:

```
<field
    name="whatever"
    layout="joomla.form.field.families"
    type="families"
/>
```

This will render `templates/your_template/html/layouts/joomla/form/field/families.php`.

It's up to you what folder structure to use, but I would not use `joomla` folder. It's meant for core layouts.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, will test this right away.

Comment: `'/templates/your_template/html/layouts'` that's no good for me unfortunately, I need to have it in `templateName/layouts` folder to access from `templateName/fields/customField.php` field so I can easily work with `dirname(__FILE__)` and avoid quering the database for the `templateName`.

Comment: As I said, you can use any folder structure you want. This just shows how to register layout paths correctly. You can use `dirname()` or anything else here, no problem. If you need template name, you can also get it from the form using `$this->form->getValue('template')`.

Comment: Considering the function you provided and the modifications I proposed based on the folder structure, what would be the string of the layout path? I can imagine it's not going to be anything like `joomla.form.fields.myfield`.

Comment: Layout is relative to available layout paths. If you use `dirname(__FILE__)` as layout path in `templates/templateName/fields/customField.php` (which results in `templates/templateName/fields`) and field layout is `joomla.form.field.myfield`, the resulting layout file is `templates/templateName/fields/joomla/form/fields/myfield.php`.

Comment: That's sweet. Gonna try that right now.

Comment: Yes, that worked. `this->layout = 'joomla.form.field.myfield'`, and added `dirname(dirname(__File__)) . '//layouts'`, then changed my layouts folder in `mytemplate/layouts` to fit the structure, and it works, 100%, applying the change to other custom fields now. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

OK so based on the new [documentation resource](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout) I found, I can actually set an independent layout for anything related to custom form fields, exactly what I wanted really. I don't need to make this field generally available for users via `com_fields`, just a quick and totally Joomla based tool for building specific admin forms.

So I removed most of the code you see above, I basically re-purposed the `getInput()` method to just call the layout I need and let it go.

```
/**
 * Method to get the field input markup.
 */
protected function getInput()
{
    $value = $this->value ? (array) $this->value : array();

    // Prepare data for renderer
    $data    = parent::getLayoutData();
    $tmpl    = null;
    $forms   = array();
    $control = $this->name;

    try
    {
        // Prepare the form template
        $formname = 'subform.' . str_replace(array('jform[', '[', ']'), array('', '.', ''), $control);
        $tmpl = JForm::getInstance($formname, $this->formsource, array('control' => $control));

        // Prepare the forms for exiting values
        $tmpl->bind($value);
        $forms[] = $tmpl;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    $data['tmpl']      = $tmpl;
    $data['forms']     = $forms;
    $data['control']   = $control;
    $data['fieldname'] = $this->fieldname;

    static $unique_subform_id = 0;
    $data['unique_subform_id'] = ('sr-' . ($unique_subform_id++));

    // Prepare renderer
    $layout = new JLayoutFile('families', JPATH_ROOT.'/ANY_PATH_TO/layouts');
    $html = $layout->render($data);

    // Render
    return $html;
}
```

While the original method pointed to an external renderer and a bunch of external layouts, something generic for a more broad use, I've added

```
 // Prepare renderer
 $layout = new JLayoutFile('families', JPATH_ROOT.'/ANY_PATH_TO/layouts');
 $html = $layout->render($data);
```

Now this custom field is unique and only uses its own layout for its purpose.