# Joomla 4 - import parent field class into extending field class issue finding the files

Tags: custom-field, form-fields-types, joomla-4.x

Testing my Joomla 3.9 extensions in Joomla 4, some of them didn't work, because, as instructed with the (probably) [old documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) my custom fields use

```
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
require_once JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries/joomla/form/fields/list.php';
```

and they don't work, so this results in

```
Warning: require_once(mysite/libraries/joomla/form/fields/list.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
site\plugins\editors-xtd\vimeo\models\fields\customField.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'site/libraries/joomla/form/fields/list.php' in site\plugins\editors-xtd\vimeo\models\fields\customField.php on line 5
```

This means I have to use namespaces, and after some investigation into core Joomla fields, here's what I came up with

```
//jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
//require_once JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries/joomla/form/fields/list.php';

use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\Field\ListField;

// FormHelper::loadFieldClass('Joomla\CMS\Form\Field\ListField'); // also tried
FormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');


class FormFieldCustomField extends ListField {

  protected $type = 'CustomField';
  // methods and stuff
}
```

This makes it that instead of my field being rendered properly, I get a `text` field, strangely enough, it also loads the JS/CSS assets.
My `getInput()` method process the form values without using a layout, perhaps that's the issue in this case, but I don't actually know.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Could you try using `FormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');` instead and see what happens?

Comment: @Lodder the same. Just a simple `text` field there.

Comment: `use Joomla\CMS\Form\Field\ListField;` is the correct way to import field class. It's your field that's not found. Namespaced class need to adhere to naming conventions and folder structure. Your field does not. It's also unclear how you're trying to load the field class in the form. Have you made any changes since your previous question?

Comment: I use the same way as described in my [answer here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24660/13509), and as for how the field is called into the form, I explained [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24685/joomla-4-how-to-set-namespace-for-custom-field-addfieldprefix).

Comment: @thednp -  You’re jumping a bit from one subject to another. First thing first. 1. Load a form properly into a layout. Any simple form. It’s really not that hard. 2. Create a custom form field properly. Then put the two together and it’s done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the problem is. The naming scheme with Joomla 4 is different not only by the missing `J` but also word order. Also folder structure and other classes deprecated/changed.

In this very example `FormFieldCustomField` should be `CustomFieldField` if I were to manage to register the namespace (I'm totally new to this stuff), instead I better use this `JFormFieldCustomField extends JFormFieldList` and it works just fine, probably until Joomla 5.